# Using PHP identical comparision operators with primitive types does make any sense?

Tags: php, comparison, operators, logical-operators

Can't get the point of `===` and `!==` with primitive types:

```
$a === $b TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
$a !== $b TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.
```

The assuming that `$request->getMethod()` returns `GET` or `POST` (as `string`) and that `$form->isValid()` returns a boolean `true` or `false`, the following code:

```
if('POST' === $request->getMethod() || (false === $form->isValid())) :
endif;
```

Does make any sense in respect of this shorter one:

```
if('POST' == $request->getMethod() || !$form->isValid()) :
endif;
```

Comment: The entire point of those type-sensitive comparison operators is to put to rest the type-juggling annoyances associated with PHP's primitive types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have truty and falsy values in PHP. For instance, `0`, `''`, `array()` are falsy values. If you use `==` it will match those values with the truty/falsy values:

```
var_dump(true == 'hello'); // true because a not empty string is a truty value
var_dump(false == 0); // true
```

`===` will match not only the value but the type also:

```
var_dump(true === 'hello'); // false, true is a boolean and 'hello' a string
var_dump(false === 0); // false, false is a boolean and 0 is a string
```

This will become a problem when a function can return `0` or `false`, `strpos` for example.

---

There are also other factors with the `==`. It will type cast values to a `int` if you compare 2 different types:

```
var_dump("123abc" == 123); // true, because '123abc' becomes `123`
```

This will be problematic if you compare a password: http://phpsadness.com/sad/47

Answer (score 2):

They are sometimes necessary. For example when using `strpos` to check if a string is contained in another string you have to distinguish `0` from `false`.

wrong:

```
if(strpos($haystack,$needle))...
```

right:

```
if(strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false)...
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` will sometimes have odd behavior when comparing different types. E.g. `'POST'` would be considered equal to `0`. That's why many people usually use `===`, it avoids type-juggling problems.

In your case it shouldn't make a difference though.

Answer (score 1):

although it may not be needed,

```
(false===$form->isValid())
```

and

```
!$form->isValid()
```

are not the same as the first is checking to see if the value of `$form->isValid()` is false, while the second is checking if `$form->isValid()` is a falsey value, so for example if `$form->isValid()` returns `null` then the first statement will not evaluate to true while the second one will evluate to true.